# What is the right way to store user data then inject it with Typhoon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

In my iOS app, I have user data that gets loaded from the network and saved as a plain Objective-C object which persists its data into `NSUserDefaults`. I need to be able to log out the current user and remove it, then log in a new user and start using that one instead throughout the app. Right now it is just a singleton I'm calling `UserManager`, with a method `-(User)currentUser`.

I'm transitioning to using Typhoon framework in my (http://typhoonframework.org) for dependency injection. What is the right way to store the user data? I know I could keep my `UserManager` class, inject it everywhere I need it via Typhoon, and set it as Typhoon type `definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;`.

But if I do this, isn't it still just a singleton? I know it's a little better because it's injected into classes rather than hidden in their implementation. But, it seems like there should be a better way to just keep a `User` object somewhere and inject whichever the current one is, without wrapping it in an [injected] singleton with a getter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Typhoon!

If I understand you correctly, you need doing injecting of currentUser to your classes like as:

```
@implementation Assembly

- (User *)currentUser
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:[self userManager] selector:@selector(currentUser)];
}

- (UserManager *)userManager
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[UserManager class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I did. I was just hoping for some way to avoid a singleton user manager at all. Probably there is no way and I was just trying to square a circle.